# Windows authentication using Web API and react.js

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-web-api, windows-authentication

I have a react application as a front end and ASP.NET Web API as backend. I have used the `xhtml, axios` request from reactjs but the code `User.Identity.Name` never picks logged in user name.

When I access web ap method directly in browser the code User.Identity.Name runs successfully. 
I need to manage windows authentication from reactjs to web api.

Comment: Have you had any luck resolving this issue? I am also looking for help with a similar setup.

Comment: You can simply add [Authorize] attribute to the method you want windows authentication and enable the windows authentication in IIS.

Comment: @ImranYaseen, I am having the same issue, could you please suggest what you have done or can we connect through email?